# Why is the text ignored by Mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with my PHP code. The problem lies in `$_GET['id']`. As you can see, I output the resultset of a user that matched with the user id.

The Question is, why do I get the same result (resultset of user with id 1) when I enter two different values on the url?

URL 1: [image: URL 1]

URL2: [image: URL 2]

Shouldn't the text (randomtext) be taken in consideration, because the code seems to ignore it.

```
<?php

    try {
        $db = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=ptp', 'root', 'root');
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
    } catch (PDOException $e) {

    }
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :id";

    echo $id . '<br/>';

    $query = $db->prepare($sql);

    $query->bindParam(':id', $id);
    $query->execute();


        while($r = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            print_r($r);
        }

    ?>
```

Comment: Put `var_dump($e->getMessage());` in your `catch` statement

Comment: I've tried it, but the result I'm getting isn't an error, but the resultset of user 1!

Comment: Both of your examples have an id of 1

Comment: well, since (hopefully) the database-field `id` is an integer, php tries to cast "1randomtext" as integer. which evaluates to 1. mystery solved.

Comment: try this: `$query->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);`

Comment: But Shouldn't "1randomtext" not return any row, because 1randomtext != 1 Fred?

Comment: Maybe try $query->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);

Comment: Tried, but didn't work :( mister martin

Comment: Make sure your id column is INT and not Varchar but yeah that is weird

Comment: Ah, so problem is that you don;t want to display data, maybe when isint($id) == false then stop script

Comment: $id = intval($_GET['id']); try that

Comment: Have thougth about that Maytyn

Comment: casting the variable to (int) did a good job by removing all excess text! but 1randomtext still showed the same result!

Comment: What want Fred is that when I search for user "1randomtext", it should return no user because no user have that id!

Comment: Here, use this instead http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php there are other functions on PHP.net that will check if it's an int **OR** string and if it contains either/or. All this set inside a conditional statement.

Comment: You Common Sense XD I had a huge problem trying to formulate this question to begin with!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like PHP, MySQL will cast the string `"1random"` to int `1`. So if your id field is a number, the query will be seen as `"SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 1"` even if there is some random text after the 1

just try this in PHP : `var_dump('1dfg' == 1)` it will return true. it's the same in MySQL.

However, if you try to find a user with id `"dfg1"`, nothing will be returned because this string can't be casted as an int.

Comment: Thanks that explained a whole lot to me. The solution I'm going with, is to cast the integer!

Comment: @phadam can you explain, why would you cast?

Comment: yes, that is a good practice to validate the data even if the code works without validation. if you expect an int, accept only ints and do not rely on automatic type translation

Comment: To Your common Sense:

Here is the thing, I need to cast because I want to remove the text! Why 
would I remove the text? Because I'm using 2 tables, one for the user and one that keeps track of how many unique visitors the user have gotten. Because the tracker have a varchar(tracker table) and the user id(user table) is an int the, "1randomtext" is only recognized by the user table as "1randomtext" is automatically converted to 1, whereas in a varchar field, "1randomtext" is NOT automatically converted to an in, it basically stays the same. I hope you understand to some extent!

Comment: And if you wounder why I don't just convert the varchar field in tracker table to an int, that's because I take visitor ip + userid and hash them! That's why it needs to be a varchar field!

Comment: @phadam if ID is varchar then use PDO::PARAM_STR